# PHP, How to make a shorten string without losing informations

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I'm using [codeigniter 3 ecryption library](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html) with default settings from the [codeigniter PHP framework](http://www.codeigniter.com) to crypt some simple alphanumeric strings.

Here's a small example on how it works inside a codeigniter helper:

```
<?php
    function shortCrypt($string) {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('encryption');
        return $CI->encryption->encrypt($string);
    }
```

The returned crypted string is too long for my purposes and i would like to make it shorter without losing any information. I thought to pass the AES-128 crypted string via md5 to reach a 32 characters lenght but the only problem is i can't obtain the original string back.

Is there a way to "compress" the AES-128 crypted string to obtain a shorter one without losing the original?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Zip it :) I know it may sound stupid, but why not.

Comment: What are you doing with the encrypted string that it length matters?

Comment: The encrypted string is sent to a webpage viewed by users. In this page could be a lot of text and contents sent via ajax so i need to compress it a lot to have better performance...

Comment: Just an idea: use gzip for http transfer?

Comment: Zip it *before* encrypting it, because ciphertexts are not compressable.